# How to formulate a mathematical equation for the grid method of multiplication?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

The formula for multiplication is simply successive additions:

$$
r \cdot  s = \sum_{i=1}^{s} r
$$

Someone on social media said that "multiplication doesn't have a formula, it only has a method," now to prove them wrong I must show that the [Multiplication algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm) taught in grade school can be re-written as an equation that encodes those steps. Is it possible? Because I believe I am simply missing the mathematical vocabulary to express this.

Here is an example, $34 × 13$ can be used with the grid method to make this grid:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
x  & 30  & 4  \\ \hline
10 & 300 & 40 \\ \hline
3  & 90  & 12 \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Now, summing up all the blocks $(300 + 40) + (90 + 12) = 340 + 102 = 442$.

A fun exercise would be to show that both equations are equivalent, however, I'm having trouble formulating the second equation. Specifically with how to represent a number in its expanded form using a summation.

Comment: What does this person understand under a "formula" ? As long as $s$ is a non-negative integer, the above formula is valid. The method we learnt in school is just much more efficient and needs much less space to be done.

Comment: Noone would add $111$ numbers $345$ together to determine the value of $111\cdot 345$ , but it is an utterly valid way to get the result.

Comment: To put words on this "grid method", it just relies on the **distributivity** of multiplication over addition : $(30+4) \times (10+3)=30 \times 10 + \cdots  + 4 \times 3$. In addition (pun intended) in a minor way, this "method" uses **associativity** of addition if one considers the use of parentheses.

Comment: I want to encode that method in a more "expressive" way that emphasises the use of distributivity. I think I might have an attempt. Posting soon.

Comment: My advice is not to fight about math on social media. It doesn't improve anybody's life.

Comment: Haha no, I'm not fighting with anyone, I just saw two people fighting and it piqued my curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have found the way to write this method as a formula. Here is my attempt:

I think the formula is more readable using helper functions, so I introduce 3 helper functions first:

1. $l(n) = \left \lfloor \log _{10} n \right \rfloor + 1$ to get the total digits in a number
2. $d(n, i) = \left \lfloor \frac{n \mod 10^i}{10^i-1} \right \rfloor$ to extract the $i$th digit of $n$ where $i \ge 1$
3. $e(n, i) = d(n, i) \times_{easy} (10^i-1)$ to get the first row/column elements of the grid (i.e. extracting 30 and 4 from 34).

Note that I am using $\times_{easy}$ instead of $\times$ to emphasize that it's easier for the human mind to do a multiplication by numbers that have trailing zeroes and only one or two leading digits.

This method is easy to encode in the programming language, but this is an effort to do it in "math language"

$$
r \times s = \sum_{i=1}^{l(r)} \left ( e(r,i) \times_{easy} \sum_{j=1}^{l(s)} e(s, j) \right )
$$

So here, $\sum$s are like nested for-loops, with the termination condition being the length of rows/columns of the grid.

---

I wrote a program to test this out, with print statements that suggest that the program follow grid multiplication:

```
let l = (n) => Math.floor(Math.log10(n)) + 1
let d = (n, i) => Math.floor(n % Math.pow(10, i) / Math.pow(10, i-1))
let e = (n, i) => d(n, i) * Math.pow(10, i-1)


let multiply = (r, s) => {
    let res = 0
    for(let i = 1; i <= l(r); i++) {
        let rowNum = e(r, i)
        for(let j = 1; j <= l(s); j++) {
            let columnNum = e(s, j)
            let block = rowNum * columnNum
            console.log(`(${rowNum} * ${columnNum}) = ${block}`)
            res = res + block
        }
    }
    return res
}
```

I believe the program is a direct translation of the equation.

```
> multiply(34, 13)
(4 * 3) = 12
(4 * 10) = 40
(30 * 3) = 90
(30 * 10) = 300
442
```

---

It also occurred to me while writing this that if you memorize the table below, everything else is just $+$ and $\times_{easy}$s. My guess for $\times_{easy}$ being easy is that once you get this table in your long-term working memory, it's like a $O(1)$ hash-table lookup. So when my (future) kids ask me why they need to learn multiplication tables, I'll direct them to this answer.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
x & 2  & 3  & 4  & 5  & 6  & 7  & 8  & 9  \\ \hline
2 & 4  & 6  & 8  & 10 & 12 & 14 & 16 & 18 \\ \hline
3 & 6  & 9  & 12 & 15 & 18 & 21 & 24 & 27 \\ \hline
4 & 8  & 12 & 16 & 20 & 24 & 28 & 32 & 35 \\ \hline
5 & 10 & 15 & 20 & 25 & 30 & 35 & 40 & 45 \\ \hline
6 & 12 & 18 & 24 & 30 & 36 & 42 & 48 & 54 \\ \hline
7 & 14 & 21 & 28 & 35 & 42 & 49 & 56 & 64 \\ \hline
8 & 16 & 24 & 32 & 40 & 48 & 56 & 64 & 72 \\ \hline
9 & 18 & 27 & 36 & 45 & 54 & 63 & 72 & 81 \\ \hline
\end{array}

I also realized that the grid method essentially breaks a hard multiplication into $l(r) \cdot l(s)$ easy multiplications and $l(r) \cdot l(s) - 1$ additions. Trading *hardness* of operations for more operations. Which makes me think it is just a version of the first equation on the "hardness to # of operation" spectrum. I don't think I'm equipped to write a proof showing that they are equivalent, **yet**.